# Continuously write to S3 file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I want to store user action logs continuously to s3 file for that session.

Requirements:

1. for a session single file
2. continuous write operations to s3
3. should be able to download that file at the end of the session.

Dont want to create new file for single session, want to update same file. Please suggest only AWS solutions.

Do i need to create stream and use it with s3 or using mediator storage system and push once in while.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in Amazon S3 are immutable -- they cannot be modified after they are created.

From your description, a good solution would be to use [Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html). Your app can stream data to the Firehose and it will combine data together based on size or time. A long session might therefore produce multiple output files, so you would need a separate process that combines those files together into a single file.

Comment: So if use dynamodb to insert all the rows and later read all and create one file and upload it to s3. is this approach is good enough ?

Comment: I need one file for a session, and the size of the file will be 1kb to 50MB max.

Comment: could you suggest any other solution or idea that may work? in my case, I will be getting continuous insertion for a session and once it ends I need to create a File(50MB max).